# oracle trigger before update purchase

Tags: oracle, triggers, updates

people try to buy or sell
how can I raise an error message if the person has not enough money to buy or have not enough quantity to sell the item.

example. 
person1 buy an item $100, person1 account balance=$50.

raise an error "not enough money to buy".

person1 buy 2 item1, Transaction only has 1 item1 to sell.

raise an error "the item is out of the store"

Table

```
Account
account number pk
account balance

People
people number pk
account number 

Portfolio
portfolio number pk
people number fk
portfolio descrption

Stock 
stockCode pk
stock name 

Transaction 
portfolio number pk
stockCode pk
transaction date pk 
BuyorSell
quantity
price_per_share
```

how many do I need to and how to pass the parameter 
because I need to use many different columns from different table

It is hard for a beginner. 
I am a beginner try to learn.
please help me out

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-trigger/